# Name of vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, terminology

If $X$ is vector space over field $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$ we call it real vector space or complex vector space.
If we add structure of inner(scalar) product to complex vector space we call it unitary space.But what about real vector space case? Is there name for it or we just call it real vector space with inner product ?

Comment: The term 'inner product space' is used in both real and complex case.

Comment: Wikipedia: A *Euclidean vector space* is a finite-dimensional inner product space over the real numbers.

Comment: @DietrichBurde  So there is no specific name for real vector space with inner product (infintite and finite dimensional together )